# MPI_Send with type created through MPI_Type_create_darray

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, openmpi

I have the following code

```
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

int n_chunks = 16;

assert(n % n_chunks == 0);
int chunk_size = n / n_chunks;

int psizes[2] = {0, 0};
MPI_Dims_create(world_size, 2, psizes);

MPI_Datatype *dist_types = (MPI_Datatype *) malloc(world_size * sizeof(MPI_Datatype));
for (int i = 0; i < world_size; i++) {
  int sizes[2] = {n, n};
  int distribs[2] = {MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC, MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC};
  int dargs[2] = {chunk_size, chunk_size};

  MPI_Type_create_darray(world_size, i, 2,
                         sizes, distribs, dargs, psizes,
                         MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &dist_types[i]);
  MPI_Type_commit(&dist_types[i]);
}

MPI_Request *send_requests;
if (rank == 0) {
  send_requests = (MPI_Request *) malloc(world_size * sizeof(MPI_Request));
  for (int i = 0; i < world_size; i++) {
    MPI_Isend(&A[0][0], 1, dist_types[i],
              i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_requests[i]);
  }
}

int dist_size;
MPI_Type_size(dist_types[rank], &dist_size);
dist_size /= sizeof(double);

double *D = (double *) malloc(dist_size * sizeof(double));

MPI_Request recv_request;
MPI_Irecv(D, dist_size, MPI_DOUBLE,
          0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_request);

MPI_Wait(&recv_request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

if (rank == 0) {
  MPI_Waitall(1, send_requests, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
}

int m = n / psizes[0];

if (rank == 0) {
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      printf("%.2lf ", D[i * m + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

When I print out the matrix `D`, I don't get a block cyclic view of `A` as I'd expect. Rather, the entries are all jumbled up and apart from the top row they look quite random.

Hence, my question is, can I generally expect this to work or are you not really supposed to use `MPI_Type_create_darray` in this situation. I'm wondering because from what I could find online, people only mention the function in the context of MPI-IO and I couldn't locate a single example of it being used in a way similar to what I have.

I'm an MPI novice, so maybe I'm just doing something wrong that's unrelated to the type I'm using. Also, I did read that it's not really ideal to distribute your matrix this way and rather use MPI-IO, but I can't really change that.

Comment: Please always include a full example. For example, we do not know how A was declared.

Comment: Also include your `mpirun` command line.

Comment: The count is wrong in MPI_Waitall - it should be world_size not 1 - but I doubt that this is the issue.

Comment: Why are you only printing D on rank 0? You send the subarrays to do different ranks so surely each rank needs to print its portion?